# Разрешение экрана

Tags: php, экран

Как можно по средством PHP узнать разрешение экрана посетителя сайта? А если возможно, то размер окна браузера тоже. Без использования JS!!

Comment: А что если записать в куки ajascrip-ом??

Comment: Без JS никак! Тонкости и причины уже давно избиты) JS'ом передавать в куки!

Comment: Интересно зачем в php получать разрешение экрана?) JS для этого используйте.

Answer (score 2):

[этот же вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357245/mobile-device-resolution-width-height-screen-size-header)
А вообще же лучше сделать промежуточную страницу на которой Javascript определяет необходимые параметры клиента и делает автоматический редирект далее.

Comment: Я так понимаю, эти заголовки посылает только мобилка. А на ПС как?

Answer (score 0):

*Посредством* PHP узнать разрешение экрана посетителя сайта **невозможно**.

Comment: Возможно для мобильных устройств, которые посылают хедеры с размером экрана (см ответ ниже от @ReinRaus)